# Writing values from xml file accessed via document() by matching attribute values from input file and accessed file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm fairly new to XSLT and I'm trying to accomplish the following:

**The input file looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <para>
    Some text
    <frag id="1"/> 
    Some text 
    <frag id="2"/> 
    Some text
    <frag id="3"/>
  </para>
</root>
```

The `<frag id="x"/>` elements are supposed to be replaced by the values of the corresponding elements in another file, which is accessed by using the document() function in the stylesheet.

**The file accessed via document() looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
     <frag id="1">X</frag>
     <frag id="2">Y</frag>
     <frag id="3">Z</frag>
</root>
```

**The result should look like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <para>
    Some text
    X 
    Some text 
    Y
    Some text
    Z
  </para>
</root>
```

I've tried many variations of xpath expressions, combinations of loops and if statements, etc.
The follwoing XSL is one of these variations which produced output which was closest to the desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="frag">   

     <xsl:for-each select="document('frag.xml')/root/frag/@id = frag/@id">

       <xsl:value-of select="document('frag.xml')/root/frag"/>

     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT writes all element values of frag.xml at every `<frag id="x"/>` in the input file.
My problem is that I don't know how to select the corresponding element value after testing for equal attribute values.
I hope someone will help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get this to work perfectly - don't have an XML editor right now, nor do online editors like `document()` calls, but this is the kind of thing you are looking for.

The first template is the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which is always a hand base case for when you want to "keep most of the input file, but just change some small parts".

The second transform matches the `frag` nodes on the input document and then replaces them with the appropriate one from the `frag.xml` file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="frag">
    <xsl:variable name='id' select="@id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="document('frag.xml')//frag[@id=$id]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! And the best is that I learned something new. The identity transform. Thank you very much.